# How to update plotly plot in offline mode (Jupyter notebook)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly, offline-mode

I would like to build a simple interface with plotly and ipywidgets inside Jupyter Notebook (offline mode) and I am wondering how to update the plot if I want to add extra data. Here is my code:

```
import plotly
from plotly.offline import iplot
from plotly.graph_objs import graph_objs as go
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

trace_high = go.Scatter(
                x=[1,2,3,4],
                y=[4,6,2,8],
                name = "High",
                line = dict(color = '#7F7F7F'),
                opacity = 0.8)


data = [trace_high]

def plot_extra_data(drop):
    if drop["new"] == "2":
        trace_low = go.Scatter(
                x=[1,2,3,4],
                y=[1,7,3,5],
                name = "Low",
                line = dict(color = 'green'),
                opacity = 0.8)
        data.append(trace_low)
        fig.update(data=data)

drop = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=['1', '2', '3'],
    value='1',
    description='Number:',
    disabled=False,
)

drop.observe(plot_extra_data, "value")

display(drop)
fig = dict(data=data)
iplot(fig)
```

Any comments/suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: in this case, it is easier to redraw the graph. you can put the code that draws the plot inside a function and link it to your widget using `interact`: http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html

Comment: @byouness Thank you for you suggestion but the usage of  interact has some limitations I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @chemist can you enumerate some of those limitations? It would help me decide what the best choice is for my current application.

Answer (score 2):

Crazy how everyone seem to be confused about interacting with offline plotly charts!

Still it is fairly simple taking benefit of property assignment (e.g. see this [documentation](http://conference.scipy.org/proceedings/scipy2018/pdfs/jon_mease.pdf) although it is now partly deprecated).

The naive snippet example below updates a `plotly.graph_objs.FigureWidget()` as user interacts via a `dropdown` widget. In fact, the `pandas.DataFrame()` containing the xaxis and yaxis data of the chart is sliced along a `Commodity` dimension the user wants to display the line chart of.

The most tedious part probably is getting all additional library requirements set if you are using `jupyterlab`

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import ipywidgets as widgets

df = pd.DataFrame({'cmdty' : ['beans', 'beans', 'beans', 'corn', 'corn', 'corn'],
                'month' : [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
                'value' : [10.5, 3.5, 8.0, 5.0, 8.75, 5.75]})

items = df.cmdty.unique().tolist()

cmdty = widgets.Dropdown(options=items,
                    description='Commodity')

def response(change):
    c = cmdty.value
    df_tmp = df[df.cmdty == c]
    x0 = df_tmp['month'] # Useless here as x is equal for the 2 commodities
    x1 = df_tmp['value']
    fig.data[0].x = x0 # Useless here as x is equal for the 2 commodities
    fig.data[0].y = x1

fig = go.FigureWidget(data=[{'type' : 'scatter'}])

cmdty.observe(response, names='value')
display(widgets.VBox([cmdty, fig]))
```

Comment: How will this code look like if you need to append new data to the graph. Say, you start with one point and add a new point to the graph every second. Can you do it without re-drawing the graph?

Comment: I actually have all data available. I just want to display it in animated way. I wonder if there's an example of using batch_animate option.

Comment: Two keys: 1. use `FigureWidget` instead of `Figure`; 2. use `display` instead of `iplot` to show the figure.